# WinRT ListView hide ScrollBar?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using WinRT XAML [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) in my desktop app.

While user interact with the listview, it shows a vertical scroll bar on the side. I want to hide this scroll bar always. I did some search with no luck. I've tried

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="False"
```

but it didn't work.

Can someone please help out on this issue? Is it possible to hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is not a boolean. It's an enum, try:

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```